# how to cube a number many times depending on the input

Tags: c

Goodevening everyone, i'm learning now to loop an array of numbers, and i'm just wondering,
how can i square the numbers in my array depending on the input of how many times i should square it

```
int main() {
     int nums[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int loop;
   int a;`enter code here`
   int pro,pro1,pro2,pro3,pro4;
   int spacing = 3;
   int i = 0
   scanf("%d", &a);
   
   do{
    pro = pow(nums[0],2);
    pro1 = pow(nums[1],2);
     pro2 = pow(nums[2],2);
      pro3 = pow(nums[3],2);
       pro4 = pow(nums[4],2);

    i++
    
   }while (i != a);
          
      printf("%0*d\n", spacing, pro);
       printf("%0*d\n", spacing, pro1);
       printf("%0*d\n", spacing, pro2);
       printf("%0*d\n", spacing, pro3);
       printf("%0*d\n", spacing, pro4);
      
  


 return 0;
}
```

this is my code so far, i wanted to loop it, and get the results like this:

```
001
016
081
256
625
```

or like this

```
001
256
6561
65536
390625
```

but i always get this:

```
 001
 004
 009
 016
 025
```

please help me understand thank you

Comment: Just clarifying. Do you intend to raise each number of your array to the power of n where n is the number given as an input by the user ?

Comment: Are you aware that mathematically, `(x^n)^m = x^(nm)`? This greatly simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strong error and a number of possible improvements in your code.

The error has already be identified by @SylvainChaugny and is that you re-use original `nums` value on each and every iteration. The improvements are:

- you are using 5 variables `pro` to `pro5` and process them the same. Better to make an array for them, or even better re-use the `nums` array.
- if you want to later extend your program to 6 values, you would have to consistently look through the code to search what needs to be changed: better to use a constant or as you have a literal initialization ask the size to the compiler
- you are using `pow` to process integer values. This is not efficient because as `pow` takes and returns double values you force a conversion from int to double and back. In addition it might be dangerous for large values: a double has less precision than an int on 64 bits architectures (48 mantissa bits for a double, 64 bits for an int). So it can lead to incorrect results.

So your code could become:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int len = sizeof (nums)  / sizeof (*nums); // idiomatic way for the length of an array
   int a;
   int spacing = 3;
   scanf("%d", &a);

    for (int i=0; i<a; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<len; j++) {
            nums[j] = nums[j] * nums[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%0*d\n", spacing, nums[i]);
    }

 return 0;
}
```

It is shorter to type (not only laziness but also less sensitive to typos) and it gives the expected result ;-). In addition, if you want to add a value to the array, it can be done be changing one single line.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you always reassign your `pro` variables to the exact same value (`pow(nums[0], 2), pow(nuws[1], 2), ...`.

So no matter what the value of `a` is, you always will have your `pro3` variable to be equal to `pow(nums[3], 2)`.

You first have to assign the initial values to your `pro` variables, then use them in the calls to `pow()`, to be able to square your previous result.